# Can not convert batch to pandas data frame with tf.data.map

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tensorflow 2 to train a classifier. I have read a very large csv file (some int features, some float features and outcome column) with `tensorflow.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`. How can I convert each batch to pandas data frame with `tf.data.map`?

Tutorial is very confusing. any suggestions please

Answer (score -1):

Just call `pd.DataFrame` on the batch?

```
import  tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset('iris.csv', batch_size=8)

example = next(iter(ds))

pd.DataFrame(example)
```

```
   sepallength  sepalwidth  petallength  petalwidth        variety
0          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2      b'Setosa'
1          5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8  b'Versicolor'
2          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2      b'Setosa'
3          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0   b'Virginica'
4          5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3  b'Versicolor'
5          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3  b'Versicolor'
6          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3      b'Setosa'
7          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2      b'Setosa'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 6 in record is not a valid int32: 2541585300 [Op:IteratorGetNext]
also gets thrown some runs

Comment: What's weird is it worked the first run